# Comparing chi-squared tests

Tags: statistics, data-science, chi-squared, statistical-test

I want to compare the chi-squared test and the one with continuity correction, in terms of their level and power. My idea is to iterate through Bernoulli distribution from 2 to 1200 samples and 500 times each and then to test chi.squared(correction = true) and chi.squared(correction = false) and to create a result table.

```
B=500
Array=c(4, 8, 16, 32, 64.....

For n in Array
 C1=empty
 C2=empty
  For i to B
    ... S1,S2 = two Samples of size n ...
    C1.add(chi.squred(S1,S2, correction=true))
    C2.add(chi.squred(S1,S2, correction=false))
```

I don't know is this the right way of doing so and how should I proceed? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have any code already? Very interesting @Dorde Klisure

Comment: Yes, I came up with the solution. Will post it :)

Comment: Have you posted the solution (as an answer)?